# Copy a string to another string Valgrind safe

Tags: c

earlier today i asked a question about a valgrind error i get, since i got no solution i'll have to try to get to a solution another way.

```
int login(char* input, int input_length)
```

this is the function prototype i have atm.
i will get an input, which should be base64 encoded, so i decode it(that function works and generates no errors) and will save the returned char* into a new char*(the function calloc's memory for the return).

ideally the end return(if the user input is in the right format) should look like this

```
username:password
```

How can i reliably find the ':' and copy the username and the password in 2 different char* pointers. i know i will have to dynamically(depending on length of both) allocate memory. i also know how to get the username, rough code:

```
int temp;
char* username;
char* buffer;
buffer = strchr(input, ':');
temp = strlen(input) - strlen(buffer);
username = calloc(temp, sizeof(char));
strncpy(username, input, temp);
```

now buffer is pointing to the ':' and i do not know what char will follow, if any. How can i now, without having the risk of uninitalised variables, get the password if there is any?

Sidenote: i will check input if it is NULL and also the decoded char* will be checked if it is NULL, if either is true, the function ends with a return.

```
char* decoded = NULL; //So it doesn't point to memory i don't "own"
if(input != NULL) {
    decoded = base64_decode(input, input_length);
}
passlocation = strchr(decoded, ':');
```

Comment: You can write: `length = buffer - input` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the `null` terminator and add it where it's missing too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int 
main(void)
{
    const char *input = "user:password";

    char *separator;
    char *user;
    char *password;
    size_t length;

    separator = strchr(input, ':');
    if (separator == NULL) // No separator
        return -1;
    // Compute the length using pointer arithmetic
    length = (ptrdiff_t) (separator - input);
    if (length == 0) // Separator is the first character
        return -1;
    user = malloc(length + 1);
    if (user == NULL) // Cannot allocate memory
        return -1;
    user[length] = '\0'; // Always Remember the `null` terminator
    memcpy(user, input, length);

    password = strdup(separator + 1);
    if (password != NULL)
        fprintf(stdout, "User: %s\nPassword: %s\n", user, password);
    free(password);
    free(user);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you put some example code of what you mean in there, i don't know what you mean by the that.

Comment: if i use calloc to allocate the memory i can skip the user[length] = '\0', right?

Comment: You can, but then you will be initializing all the bytes to `0` to immediately overwrite them and that's not a smart thing to do. The worse thing about `calloc()` is that when handling strings you want to be sure your function is copying the exact number of bytes and not less, `calloc()` will hide that for you. Don't use `calloc()` unless you are 100% positive that it's the PERFECT solution, i.e. You really want a buffer filled with zeroes. The beautiful thing about [tag:c], is that you use the exact amount of memory you need, so don't use `calloc()` here.

Comment: your code works totally fine, but i get a valgrind error saying "conditional jump or move depends on uninitalised value" in the line "seperator = strchr(decoded, ':'). i edited my original post to show you the snipped that gives me an error.

Comment: @MeikVtune It's your input string, use `--track-origins=yes` to find where. Meik, change your pointer declaration style to avoid future headache. Use `char *pointer;` instead of `char* pointer`;.

Comment: @iharob i did find the error! the function i am calling(base64_decode) had an uninitialised value which in the end caused valgrind to mark it as an error when comparing something to it(i did not know that valgrind only marks problems when you start to compare things without showing you the root of the problem)

Comment: Yes, valgrind does check for uninitailised values when you read them. Using `--track-origins` is very helpful to find where